# Made dynamic highstock with PHP data

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I made a dynamic highstock (highchart) like this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/), but with data from PHP. I have tried my code, but the results did not appear. How to make dynamic highstock with PHP?

PHP code :

```
<?php 

include("connection.php");

$data = array();
$count = 0;
$result = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY time ASC ") or die ("Connection error");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$x = strtotime($row['time']) * 1000; 
$y =    (float)$row['temperature'];
$data[] = array($x, $y);
$count++;
}
echo json_encode($data);
mysqli_close($koneksi);
?>
```

JSON from PHP:

```
[[1535981121000,40],[1535981432000,32.9],[1535981492000,32.7],[1535981552000,32.6],[1535981618000,32.6],[1535981672000,32.6],[1535981732000,32.6],[1535981793000,32.6],[1535981854000,32.6],[1535981913000,32.5],[1535981993000,32.4],[1535982034000,32.4],[1535982215000,32.4],[1535982287000,32.3],[1535982335000,32.3],[1535982396000,32.5],[1536576266000,45.2],[1536579542000,62.2],[1536653234000,30.2]]
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;  
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'chartTemp.php',
        success: function(point) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20; 

            // add the point
            chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);

            // call it again after one second
            setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
        },
        cache: false
    });
}   
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {  
    chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: requestData
        }
    },

    time: {
        useUTC: false
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            count: 1,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '1M'
        }, {
            count: 5,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '5M'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }],
        inputEnabled: true,
        selected: 0
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },

    exporting: {
        enabled: true
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: data[]
    }]
});

    </script>
```

I changed the javascript code above from this [example](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing either,

```
// Set the JSON header (in .php)
header("Content-type: text/json");
```

Or like,

```
$.ajax({
method: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Also you have some syntax errors, at the end of javascript code add below (to confirm check in browser's console window),

```
)};
```

Your ajax call is returning all of the points in a single json, but the function you are calling looks like don't accept, so check again,

```
// add the point  
chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the chart still doesn't appear

Comment: @NyanPaw check in your browser's network tab whether is it returning correct data or not?